# With instrumentation, javassist can modify class file but how can l load a new class that created by javassist

Tags: javassist

With instrumentation, javassist can modify class file but how can l load a new class that created by javassist.
For example,ClassFileTransFormer transform a specific class named A and i created a CtClass named B with Javassist and how to use B in A.